# Android Emulator Error : Emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 cannot be started

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I am trying to start my emulator but I get this error like

**Starting emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 ...
1>Waiting for runtime checks to complete
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -no-boot-anim -avd pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28
Emulator pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 cannot be started.
Runtime checks completed
Build has been canceled.
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
Failed to open /usr/local/google/home/joshuaduong/emu/master/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qemu-android-deps/windows_msvc-x86_64/qemu.conf, err: 2
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational**

Anybody have any idea how to solve this error?? I just started building apps using Xamarin and visual studio 2019 .

Comment: Hi , have a try with [Hardware acceleration for emulator performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows) to check whether can start emulator .